# C# Optimizar código foreach

Tags: c#, unity3d

Buenas !
Tengo 3 foreach,uno para buscar cuantas carpetas hay en un directorio,otro para buscar los png que hay y otro para buscar los exe que hay.
El problema es que para buscar cada exe y luego png doi 36 vueltas ,como puedo arreglarlo?como puedo hacer que solo busque los archivos con esas extensiones y no valla comprobando toodos los archivos?
Y como puedo hacer que busque png y jpg? y lo mismo con exe y lnk?

```
foreach (var juego in data.Juegos) {
    }
    //creamos los botones por cada carpeta que tengamos en Apps
    if (Directory.Exists(rutasapp)) {
        foreach (string dataApp in Directory.GetDirectories(rutasapp)) {
            GameObject button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab) as GameObject;
            button.transform.SetParent(layout);
            button.name = "Button" + layout.childCount;
            //buscamos todos los ficheos que sean .exe y los guardamos en data

            foreach (string data in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp)) {
                if (Path.GetExtension(@data) == ".exe") {
                    //al clicar el boton ejecutamos el exe que hemos guardado anteriormente .NO FUNCIONA
                    button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Process.Start(data));
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(data);

                }

                //buscamos todas las imagenes que sean .png y las guardamos en imagenes
                foreach (string imagenes in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp)) {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@imagenes) == ".png") {
                         string imgPath = imagenes;
                            //si no exite nos muestra el mensaje de error 
                            if (!File.Exists(imgPath)) {
                                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("File doesn't exist: " + imgPath);
                                return;
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar el método GetFiles(string pattern)

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryIn);
FileInfo[] fileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.png");//Obtienes la info de los archivos con extención png
foreach (var fi in fileInfo)
{
//lo que tengas que hacer
}
```

para obtener todos los .exe solo cambias el patrón de búsqueda

```
di.GetFiles("*.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

Para filtrar el tipo de archivo en el directorio quizá puedas hacer lo siguiente:

```
  var archivosPngExe = Directory
                         .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\directorio") 
                         .Where(file => file.ToLower().EndsWith("png") || file.ToLower().EndsWith("exe"))
                         .ToList();
```